# No PDF file produced (Font Problem)

Tags: pdf-format, printing

When I want to export my notebook as a PDF document, I get the following error messages from Adobe Standard 11, which I use as PDF "printer":

> %%[ ProductName: Distiller ]%%
>
> %%[Page: 1]%%
>
> %%[Page: 2]%%
>
> %%[Page: 3]%%
>
> %%[Page: 4]%%
>
> %%[Page: 5]%%
>
> %%[Page: 6]%%
>
> %%[Page: 7]%%
>
> %%[Page: 8]%%
>
> **MathematicaMono-Bold not found, using Courier.**
>
> %%[Page: 9]%%
>
> %%[Page: 10]%%
>
> **MathematicaMono not found, using Courier.**
>
> %%[ Error: invalidfont; OffendingCommand: show ]%%
>
> Stack:
>
> ()
>
> **%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%**
>
> %%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%

**What's wrong there?
How to overcome the situation?**

I remeber that I had similar problems earlier when using some other PDF-cration mechanism. I new, the remedy there was to tell teh PDF printing tool to include all fonts which are used.

**Is this another instance of this type?**

Comment: It seems that the fonts are not installed. Maybe you have to give  Distiller, Acro etc a fresh install. In any case, you must also check the OS. Get used to specify in such cases always OS versions and the SW used. Question an admin or OS supporter. Good Luck anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to circumvent the problem: follow these hints to use **Save as** and select  there .pdf:  see https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ExportToPDF.html

According to what it shows on the screen, it goes through some printing process. And unfortunately there is a programming glitch in Mathematica: It will only export the pages selected in your last printing, if you did not print everything!

**So beware to select Print all pages** instead of some range of pages **before starting to save as *.pdf.**

I have to admit that this is not *the* answer to my two questions above

**What is Wrong here?** and

**Is this another instance of this type** (of not including special fonts, if necessary) **?**

I hope the answer helps despite this objection.